# Controller defined in a module referenced inside a directive in another module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an index.html (main entry point) and I have a main.js file, say:

```
(function() {

var pop = angular.module('mainApp', []);

pop.directive = ('directive1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: notIndex.html,
        controller: // how to reference controller1 here? ,
        controllerAs: controller1Alias
    }

    });

// pop.directives some more...

})();
```

I have a notIndex.html (template or fragment) and a corresponding controller for this html defined in notMain.js say:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('app1', []);

app.controller = ('controller1', function() {

    function1...
    function2...
    .
    .
    .
    functionN

});

})();
```

So my questions are:

1. How to reference controller1 in directive1 of notMain.js?
2. I cannot have  tags in notIndex.html (it doesn't have a header or body as templates do), right? How can I reference AngularJS directives defined in notMain.js from this html? In index.html, I suppose?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `app1` as a dependency of the `mainApp` module and it should be able to reference the controller via the controller's name. Something like this:

```
(function() {
    var pop = angular.module('mainApp', ['app1']);

    pop.directive = ('directive1', function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           templateUrl: 'notIndex.html',
           controller: 'controller1'
           controllerAs: 'controller1Alias'
       };
    });
})();
```

Noticed that I changed `app.directive` to `pop.directive`? this is because `app1` is not available in your `mainApp` closure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For question 2, am I right that the <script> tag referencing notMain.js is declared in index.html? Can notIndex.html invoke notMain.js controller after that?

Comment: if you are including script tag inside notIndex.html then it will not work, you should include the script tag in your index.html